# Wordpress モバイルバージョンエラー (Undefined index: action in)

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress のプラグインアップデート後、モバイルバージョンの上部にエラーが表示されます。

```
Notice : Undefined index: action in 
/home/users/1/candle/web/Home page address/contact/index.php
 on line 42
```

42番の文章を確認しましたが、何が問題なのかわかりません。

```php
if ($_REQUEST['action'] == 'rewrite') {
    $_POST = $_SESSION['inquiry'];
    $error['rewrite'] = true;}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP の連想配列で，存在しない key へアクセスしようとしたときに

- PHP5.4 〜 PHP7.4 ... Undefined index: {key_name} （Notice レベル）
- PHP8.0 〜 ... Undefined array key "{key_name}" （Warning レベル）

というようなエラーメッセージが表示されます．

今回の場合は `$_REQUEST` 配列の `action` という key の値を取り出して， 'rewrite' という文字列を比較しようとしているタイミングで， `$_REQUEST['action']` へのアクセスが発生していますが，このコードの実行時，この key が存在していないということです．

`$_REQUEST` は， `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_COOKIE` というスーパーグローバル変数の内容が合わさったものですので，リクエスト時にボディやクエリストリング, cookie に `action` という key で値を渡していないんだと思います．

`$_REQUEST` から得られる値というのは，クライアント側から入力される値であり，サーバー側からしたらその存在が保証されているわけでは無いため， key が無い，もしくは key があっても期待している値が入っていないことを想定したコードを書く必要があります．

今回でいうと， $_REQUEST['action'] が存在しない場合を考慮すべきですので，

```php
if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'rewrite') {
  // do something ...
}
```

と書くと安全です．

もしくは， Null 合体演算子を利用する方法も紹介します．これは PHP7 より追加された機能で，
`$_REQUEST['action'] ?? 'default_value'`
と
`isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : 'default_value'`
は等価です．

今回でいうと，

```php
if ($_REQUEST['action'] ?? '' === 'rewrite') {
  // do something ...
}
```

のように書くことで，安全に比較ができると思います．